# Cheapest 1080p HDMI Netflix device

Tags: hdmi, video, set-top-box

What is the least expensive Netflix client device that supports HDMI 1080p output and has a remote control?  It can be wired or wireless.  Bonus points it it has the ability to play video from the local LAN.

I found this [Netgear NeoTV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0092U3TKC) box on Amazon for $27.95 plus shipping, and it appears to meet my criteria, but are there any less expensive devices that will do the same thing?

Comment: Chromecast would do all this, but it's not a standalone device, as it requires a tablet or phone.

Comment: I would seriously wait till black friday and check if the amazon fire stick gets discounted (it's highly likely)

Comment: I'm not sure if Netflix currently works on Raspberry Pi (their DRM may not work with the Pi's ARM OS), but they're cheap, fully functional Linux computers with 1080p HDMI. Hopefully someone can confirm that Netflix works on them right now?

Answer (score 0):

A Google Chromecast, Amazon FireStick, Roku Stick would all do that job perfectly. I doubt that they’ll EVER get cheaper because each company wants to make a profit, and nothing is ever free.

Google Chromecast Link: https://store.google.com/us/product/chromecast

Amazon FireStick Link: [https://www.amazon.com/Fire-TV-Stick-with-Alexa-Voice-Remote/dp/B0791TX5P5](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0791TX5P5)

Roku: https://www.roku.com/products/roku-express